# how to select an option from a dropdown list in a webpage using the inner text

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

How to select an option from a dropdown list in a webpage using the inner text

below is vba code

```
Sub navigation_site_with_part_number()
    Dim eRow As Long
    Dim ele As Object
    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    RowCount = 1`enter code here
    eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    requestnumber = InputBox("Enter the request number.")
    With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "*http://www.auto.com*"
    Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop
    .document.getElementsByid("inspNumber").selectedinnertext = 2
   .document.getElementById("InspQuery_Search").Click
    Do While .Busy Or _
   .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop
    End With
```

Below is Html code:

```html
div id="RequestNumberGroup" class="form-group">
<label for="TextRequestNumber">Request Number:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="inspNumber" name="inspNumber">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="813">20190205</option>
  <option value="1034">20190426</option>
  <option value="1059">20190451</option>
  <option value="1061">20190453</option>
  <option value="1064">20190456</option>
  <option value="1065">20190457</option>
```

I expected to select the option in dropdownlist with requestnumber not option value

Comment: i am new to stack over flow.still learning to post question.sorry .but please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a select by text option in IE implementation.

1) Either gather collection/nodelist of options and loop comparing innerText against desired text string then select if found and Exit For

```
Dim options As Object, i As Long, found As Boolean

Set options = ie.document.querySelectorAll("#inspNumber options")

For i = 0 To options.length - 1
    If options.item(i).innerText = "target string" Then
        options.item(i).Selected = True
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not found Then
    'do something if not found
End If
```

2) Use [selenium vba wrapper](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) which does implement this functionality

```
Dim ele As Select
Set ele = driver.FindElementById("inspNumber").AsSelect
ele.SelectByText "Option Text"
```

---

N.B. Of course there are using attributes values and selectedIndex methods but you didn't want those.